# Basic HTTP Auth with PicketLink using JPA fails

Tags: jboss7.x, jpa-2.0, picketlink

There is functioning picketlink configuration being used by form authentication without any issues.

We are now trying to add HTTP auth to another section of the the system and it is failing - with a difficult to track down error. The stack trace of the error:

```
  17:47:10,818 WARN  [org.picketlink.authentication] (http-ayodhya/127.0.0.1:8080-8) PLINK002100: Authentication failed for account [admin].: org.picketlink.authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
        at org.picketlink.internal.AbstractIdentity.authenticate(AbstractIdentity.java:198) [picketlink-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.internal.AbstractIdentity.login(AbstractIdentity.java:105) [picketlink-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:45) [weld-core-1.1.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.proxies.Identity$1509662680$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.login(Identity$1509662680$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
        at org.picketlink.authentication.web.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:144) [picketlink-api-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:134) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:92) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.web.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:64) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:353) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:911) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$ChannelProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.IdentityManagementException: PLIDM000200: Credential validation failed [org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials@7fda5ed6].
        at org.picketlink.idm.internal.ContextualIdentityManager.validateCredentials(ContextualIdentityManager.java:185) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.internal.SecuredIdentityManager.validateCredentials(SecuredIdentityManager.java:76) [picketlink-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:45) [weld-core-1.1.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.proxies.IdentityManager$-1462534089$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.validateCredentials(IdentityManager$-1462534089$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
        at org.picketlink.authentication.internal.IdmAuthenticator.authenticate(IdmAuthenticator.java:54) [picketlink-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.internal.AbstractIdentity.authenticate(AbstractIdentity.java:185) [picketlink-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.IdentityManagementException: PLIDM000501: Could not query IdentityType using query [org.picketlink.idm.query.internal.DefaultIdentityQuery@7c8ebfec].
        at org.picketlink.idm.query.internal.DefaultIdentityQuery.getResultList(DefaultIdentityQuery.java:148) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.AbstractCredentialHandler.getAccount(AbstractCredentialHandler.java:85) [picketlink-idm-api-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.PasswordCredentialHandler.getAccount(PasswordCredentialHandler.java:148) [picketlink-idm-api-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.PasswordCredentialHandler.getAccount(PasswordCredentialHandler.java:56) [picketlink-idm-api-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.AbstractCredentialHandler.validate(AbstractCredentialHandler.java:112) [picketlink-idm-api-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.AbstractCredentialHandler.validate(AbstractCredentialHandler.java:49) [picketlink-idm-api-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.internal.AbstractIdentityStore.validateCredentials(AbstractIdentityStore.java:139) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.internal.ContextualIdentityManager.validateCredentials(ContextualIdentityManager.java:183) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        ... 42 more
Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.IdentityManagementException: Could not create [blah.blah.User@0 from entity [blah.blah.AdminUser@2bb4523d[username=admin,firstName=Test,lastName=<null>,email=admin@example.com,enabled=true,lastAccess=2013-10-11 14:37:32.419,defaultAccessLevel=<null>]].
        at org.picketlink.idm.jpa.internal.mappers.EntityMapper.createType(EntityMapper.java:209) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.jpa.internal.JPAIdentityStore.fetchQueryResults(JPAIdentityStore.java:524) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.query.internal.DefaultIdentityQuery.getResultList(DefaultIdentityQuery.java:137) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        ... 49 more
Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.IdentityManagementException: No mapper for entity type [class blah.blah.RealmTypeEntity_$$_jvst83e_bc].
        at org.picketlink.idm.jpa.internal.JPAIdentityStore.getMapperForEntity(JPAIdentityStore.java:863) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.picketlink.idm.jpa.internal.mappers.EntityMapper.createType(EntityMapper.java:184) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar:]
        ... 51 more
```

One of the odd thing is that the name of the class at the end there (`blah.blah.RealmTypeEntity_$$_jvst83e_bc`) changes with each deployment though the jvst part remains intact.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<distributable/>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>PicketLink Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.picketlink.authentication.web.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>

    <!-- This parameter is required. Here you specify which authentication scheme you want to use. This quickstart
         uses HTTP Basic. -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>authType</param-name>
      <param-value>BASIC</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- You can also provide the realm name. If this parameter is not set, defaults to 'PicketLink Default Realm' -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>realmName</param-name>
      <param-value>SECURE</param-value>
    </init-param>

  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PicketLink Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The IdentityConfiguration is provided and has the `RealmTypeEntity.class` mapped. However, it obviously doesn't have the `RealmTypeEntity_$$_jvst83e_bc` variants mapped and it is not clear where these are coming from either.

As with a lot of things picketlink, there seems to be little to no help from google :-(

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I added @Stateless annotation to the class where you invoke identity.login(). And error go away. There is example where I [tested it](https://github.com/lynx-r/picketlink-deltaspike-authorization-and-idm-custom-identity-model)

Comment: the identity.login() is invoked by the picketlink filter (org.picketlink.authentication.web.AuthenticationFilter`) - hence, I can't make it stateless... :-( `

Comment: It worked for me. I am creating a custom idm with jpa, and I was forgotten the scope of the loginController bean. Thanks!

Comment: But it didn't work with @RequestScoped. How do I use CDI beans in this case? I wouldn't like to use EJB in my project. I read those beans are for another things..

Answer (score 0):

What "other" HTTP auth are you adding to the system?  You said you were using FORM security without issues but the param-value in the code you showed says BASIC.  Is that your entire web.xml?  I've never tried mixing authType.